# XCode: switch from on-device debugging to emulator

Tags: xcode, emulation

Sorry for this question but I have spent too much time to find answer.
How can I switch back to debugging on emulator ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the *Overview* drop-down in the toolbar and tick *Simulator* instead of *Device*.

Comment: Thanks. It was hard to find because there was "Base SDK missing" - but I have set it to the last I have.